# Exception during authentication at location 'ApplyResponseGrant' with identity (rethrow:True)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, owin

> System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Server cannot append header
>   after HTTP headers have been sent.    at
>   System.Web.HttpHeaderCollection.SetHeader(String name, String value,
>   Boolean replace)    at System.Web.HttpHeaderCollection.Set(String
>   name, String value)    at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.CallHeaders.AspNetResponseHeaders.Set(String
>   key, String[] values)    at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.CallHeaders.AspNetResponseHeaders.set_Item(String
>   key, String[] value)    at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Infrastructure.OwinHelpers.SetHeaderUnmodified(IDictionary`2
>   headers, String key, String[] values)    at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Infrastructure.OwinHelpers.AppendHeaderUnmodified(IDictionary`2
>   headers, String key, String[] values)    at
>   Microsoft.Owin.HeaderDictionary.AppendValues(String key, String[]
>   values)    at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Infrastructure.ChunkingCookieManager.AppendResponseCookie(IOwinContext
>   context, String key, String value, CookieOptions options)    at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler.d__f.MoveNext()

Getting this issue? How should I try to debug? Doens't understand where to start from ?